# AF 3550 APRIL 24 2020 Paris to Detroit cancelled?

Tags: refunds

Was AF 3550 Paris to Detroit actually cancelled On April 24 2020? The airline says it STILL hasn’t been so and are refusing a refund except of taxes.

Comment: Airlines had difficult time on liquidity, so they delayed. Keep asking, because one of the deal with government (to get liquidity) was to get quickly the refunds. [In general keep asking is necessary, but in this time, you need much more perseverance]

Comment: Do you mean that the airline claims that the flight operated as scheduled, while you think it was actually cancelled? Presumably, the airline would have notified you before the flight if they cancelled it, wouldn't it?

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I received no information about either cancellation or checking in. It was a chaotic time because of Covid and because we were all was under lockdown in France I assumed that no flights were leaving the country and so never questioned the failure to give me any info.